# Where can I view the change history in PowerPoint online (Office 365)?

Tags: office-365

Where can I view the change history in PowerPoint online (Office 365)?

For example, in Google documents, I may view the change history:

[image]

I don't see any `Previous Versions` option in the Info tab:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Follow these instructions:

1. Open the presentation you want in PowerPoint Online
2. Click on the File button
3. Click on the Info tab
4. Click on Previous Versions

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your enterprise is on a semi-annual update and your Office version is not up to date to get that "Previous Versions" feature. See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-previous-versions-of-office-files-5c1e076f-a9c9-41b8-8ace-f77b9642e2c2